# SelectOneMenu Ajax Update remains one step behind

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

i have a problem with ajax update .From a SelectOneMenu component i want to select a sorting option but the ajax call is always made with the last not current option selected . 
This is the code snippet used, the update component is a LazyDataModel which data i want to sort. I am new to jsf and primefaces , hope i was clear enough.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectSortDirection" value="#{notificationListView.sortDirection}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{notificationListView.sortDirections}" var="currItem"
                                itemLabel="#{currItem.label}" itemValue="#{currItem.value}" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="notificationListDataTable"  />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: does your notificationListDataTable rely on #{notificationListView.sortDirection}" ? also take a look at this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf

Comment: Yes it uses sortDirection for the sorting order .Basically i have to values ASC and DESC and when i select one in the backend the other one is used. Edit : it's not similar to the use case from primefaces , if sortDirection is null it is set to a default value

Comment: add some print outs in your code to see where the lag happens...

Comment: I checked the setter for that field and also i used a listener to see if maybe it calls the setter again but it didn't,on the setter method the value is the old one... so i guess it's an ajax bug (maybe i need to use another attribute).

Comment: if you add a listener to ajax , in listener method you see the right value of notificationListView.sortDirection ? and does the getter of the notificationListView.sortDirection called after your listener method ?

Comment: It was a lifecycle problem , the URLAction method was called before setting the new sortDirection value so that property was injected with the wrong value in the LazyModel.On the listener the value was correct so i used that to set the correct sortDirection value . Thanks for your help , put the last comment as an answer so i can vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following  :

If you add a listener to `ajax` , in `listener` method you see the right value of `notificationListView.sortDirection` ? and does the getter of the `notificationListView.sortDirection` called after your listener method ?